# How can I use Gradle to build Android applications from the command line

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm just trying to adapt to Android Studio, and I'm not enjoying it much.

A cursory glance at the Gradle site suggests that an aim is to be able to make the same build from the command-line as the IDE. If so, presumably it's possible to use Gradle to build Android Studio projects wtihout running Android Studio.

How can I do this? Are there any online examples?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html

Answer (score 2):

**Building in Debug Mode**
For immediate application testing and debugging, you can build your application in debug mode and immediately install it on an emulator. In debug mode, the build tools automatically sign your application with a debug key and optimize the package with zipalign.
On Windows platforms, type this command:

```
> gradlew.bat assembleDebug
```

On Mac OS and Linux platforms, type these commands:

```
$ chmod +x gradlew
$ ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

To see a list of all available build tasks for your project, type this command:

```
$ ./gradlew tasks
```

**Building in Release Mode**

Build signed and aligned

If you would like, you can configure the Android build script to automatically sign and align your application package. To do so, you must provide the path to your keystore and the name of your key alias in your modules's build.gradle file. With this information provided, the build will prompt you for your keystore and alias password when you build using the release build type and produce your final application package, which will be ready for distribution.

To specify your keystore and alias, open the module build.gradle file (found in the root of the module directory) and add entries for storeFile, storePassword, keyAlias and keyPassword. For example:

```
storeFile file("myreleasekey.keystore")
keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
```

Save your changes. Now you can build a signed .apk in release mode:

```
Open a command-line and navigate to the root of your module directory.
Edit the build.gradle file to build your project in release mode:

...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("myreleasekey.keystore")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps